# DocumentListener on JTextArea how does it work?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, documentlistener

So I'm new to java and I'm currently working on my first java program which is a copy of a Notepad.

I am currently having problem with my "New" functionality, so basically my goal is if the user changed something on the document then press "New" on a new document it will show dialogbox to save then clear the textarea (this is my askToSave() method), if its an existing document then it will just save the file then clear the textarea. But if there is no changes to the document then it will just clear the textarea.

My problem is that I created a DocumentLisnter to listen to my textarea if there is changes, I have Instance Variable statusTextArea set to false then if there is changes happend on my textare it will set this value to true then if this is true it will run my save method else then just clear textarea. but it seems like even though I did not change anything on the text area it always run my askToSave() method.

This is my "New" Listener

```
public class NewMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (statusTextArea == true) {
            askToSave();
        } else {
            editorTextArea.setText("");
        }           
    }
}
```

This is my askToSave Method:

```
private void askToSave() {
    JOptionPane message = new JOptionPane();
    int x = message.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Do you want to save changes?", "DVTextEditor", message.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (x == message.YES_OPTION) {
        if(chooser.getSelectedFile() == null) {
            chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
            saveFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } else {
            saveFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        editorTextArea.setText("");
    } else if(x == message.NO_OPTION) {
        editorTextArea.setText("");
    } else {
        //meh
    }
}
```

and this is the DocumentListener:

```
public class DocListener implements DocumentListener {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        statusTextArea = true;
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        statusTextArea = true;
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        statusTextArea = true;
    }
}
```

Full Code Below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DVTextEditor {
    private JTextArea editorTextArea;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JFileChooser chooser;
    private boolean statusTextArea;

public DVTextEditor() {
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    statusTextArea = false;
}

public void go() {
    // make frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DVTextEditor");

    //make menu bar and menu
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenu formatMenu = new JMenu("Format");

    //make menu items for file menu
    JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New");
    JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");

    //add menu items in file menu
    fileMenu.add(newMenuItem);
    fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);

    //action listeners for New and Save menu items
    newMenuItem.addActionListener(new NewMenuListener());
    openMenuItem.addActionListener(new OpenMenuListener());
    saveMenuItem.addActionListener(new SaveMenuListener());

    //make menu items for format menu
    JCheckBoxMenuItem wrapMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Word Wrap ");

    //add menu items in format menu
    formatMenu.add(wrapMenuItem);

    //action listener for word Wrap item menu
    wrapMenuItem.addItemListener(new WordWrapListener());

    // add menu in menu bar
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(formatMenu);

    // make text area and put inside scrollpane
    editorTextArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
    editorTextArea.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    Font defaulFont = new Font("sanserif", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    editorTextArea.setFont(defaulFont);

    // add listener for JTextArea
    editorTextArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocListener());

    // make scrollpane then add textarea to scrollpane
    JScrollPane eScrollBar = new JScrollPane(editorTextArea);
    eScrollBar.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    eScrollBar.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    // add menu bar and text area in frame
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, eScrollBar);

    // enable frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class NewMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (statusTextArea == true) {
            askToSave();
            statusTextArea = false;
            System.out.println("Status is false");
        } 
        else {
            editorTextArea.setText("");
            statusTextArea = false;
            System.out.println("Status is false");
        }           
    }
} //end New Menu Inner Class

private void askToSave() {
    JOptionPane message = new JOptionPane();
    int x = message.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Do you want to save changes?", "DVTextEditor", message.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);

    if (x == message.YES_OPTION) {
        if(chooser.getSelectedFile() == null) {
            chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
            saveFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        } else {
            saveFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        }
        editorTextArea.setText("");
    } 
    else if (x == message.NO_OPTION) {
        editorTextArea.setText("");
    } 
    else {
        //meh
    }
}

public class DocListener implements DocumentListener {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        statusTextArea = true;
        System.out.println("Status is true!");
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        statusTextArea = true;
        System.out.println("Status is true!");
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        statusTextArea = true;
        System.out.println("Status is true!");
    }
}

public class OpenMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        chooser.showOpenDialog(frame);
        loadFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
    }
} // end Open Menu Inner Class

private void loadFile(File file) {
    StringBuilder myDoc = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            myDoc.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not read file");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    editorTextArea.setText(myDoc.toString());
    statusTextArea = false;
    System.out.println("Status is false");
}

public class SaveMenuListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        chooser.showSaveDialog(frame);
        saveFile(chooser.getSelectedFile());
    }
} // end Save Menu Inner Class

private void saveFile(File file) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        //writer.write(editorTextArea.getText());  <- does not work write only one line
        //instead of using bufferedWriter's method to write use textarea's method to write
        editorTextArea.write(writer);
        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Could not save file!");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    statusTextArea = false;
    System.out.println("Status is false");
}

public class WordWrapListener implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent e) {
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            editorTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
            editorTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            frame.repaint();
        } else {
            editorTextArea.setLineWrap(false);
            editorTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(false);
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }
} // end inner class

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DVTextEditor x = new DVTextEditor();
    x.go();
}

}
```

Comment: `but it seems like even though I did not change anything on the text area` - so what debugging did you do? Did you add any debug code to the DocumentListener so see when the methods are invoked? For example using `setText(...)` will invoke the DocumentListener. Do you ever reset the value of your "statusTextArea" variable when you load a new document?

Comment: Hi @camickr, thank you for your advice! I am now able to fix my code (see updated full code). So I took your advice as to add debugging code, I used system.out. But it seems like my approach on doing this is kinda like a bummer cuz I have to set my status to false on pretty much every time my textarea change.  my original plan is actually comparing the current file loaded to current textarea.getText() if (current file == to textarea.getText() then no change else theres change), is there a way to compare File to textarea??

Comment: There is no need to compare the file. You should only need to reset the flag (to false) when you load the file (or when you save the file). Then let the DocumentListener keep setting it to true as changes are made.

Comment: yes you're right, I kinda over did resetting the flag.Thank you so much! you are amazing!!